# Power Automate Get file content using path gets stuck

Tags: power-automate

I am having issues with this trigger. I have a flow where When a new email arrives (Outlook) > Create a file [from the attachments in the e-mail] (Sharepoint) > When a file is created (Sharepoint) > Get file content using path (Sharepoint) and it always gets stuck on that step. My flow started to run this morning and has been stuck on that step for 3 hours.